# Why should the allocated memory be released properly?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I always thought that whenever you Initialised a pointer using "new", that assigned memory would always be used for that pointer, even after the application you're programming terminates. This was till I found out that apparently memory is cleared up by the OS once the application has closed which has confused me slightly since if that's the case, then why is memory leaks within games or other applications such a problem if the memory leak is cleared once the application closes?

Comment: On modern multi-tasking operating systems a pointer is only valid withing a single *process*.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744766(v=vs.85).aspx - Please read as it describes the problem of memory leaks

Comment: As for leaks, lets say you have a loop which does some processing. This processing has some dynamic memory allocation, but the programmers forgot to free that memory at the end of the iteration. That's a leak. The memory will be reclaimed when the process end, but not during the run-time of the process.

Comment: The leak is when the application is still running and even though the process is not using that memory, another process cannot use it.

Comment: I see, I just always thought a memory leak was still a problem, even after the application closes.

Comment: It *can* be. Some lighter operating systems, especially for embedded systems, don't free resources if a process terminates. The big operating systems for modern PC-type systems (like Windows, Linux or macOS) all do though. And it's always a good habit to release what you allocate anyway.

Comment: @VTT More a fundamentally flawed understanding of what a memory leak is. codelyoko, to be clear: a memory leak is ***any time your program retains a memory allocation that it will no longer use throughout the execution of your program*** ('No longer use' can be a result of either: (a) you no longer hold a reference to that memory. **But can also** (b) refer to memory where you do hold a reference, but the logic of your program dictates it will never again be used; _which is a fundamental limitation of garbage collection frameworks_)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312113/224704

Comment: @CraigYoung I maybe should of looked into Memory Leaks a little more haha, thanks for clearing this up for me :)

Answer (score 2):

True, all the memory you allocated within your program is going to be released by the OS when you terminate it.

But there are two important factors behind this story.

1. If your program allocates memory and they are leaked, you are effectively creating areas in the computer's memory those can neither be used by your application nor by another one running parallelly. This is not good if you expect long lifespans for your programs. It might suffocate the entire system if the leak happens within a long loop.
2. If your program is going to be some kind of a single instance DLL (such as Windows in-proc/out-of-proc COM server), the entire system is in trouble. This is because the DLL will not be unloaded immediately by the OS even after the user exists the program which uses it.

Writing a program is not only the placement of the logic in your code. It is always about managing your resources accurately and efficiently too. Resources are always limited.

Comment: If i am not wrong, another thing to worry is if you are writing kernel mode code where memory is never freed automatically

Comment: Of course. Deeper the layers one goes inside the OS, lower the care the OS takes about code.