# Can I cause so many memory leaks that my computer becomes unresponsive?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I always thought that a program can't eat up all the RAM because the OS limits the total amount of memory any program can use. However, I was just trying something about memory leaks and wrote this simple C++ code to allocate as much heap as possible:

```
int main() {
    while (true)
        new int;
}
```

I ran it within my IDE while checking my (Win 10) RAM monitor and saw how it went from 8GB free (of the 16GB my computer has) before running the program to almost 0GB free, and suddenly the whole thing became unresponsive (even the mouse was frozen). I waited a couple minutes and nothing happened so I had to force a restart.

My question is: was I wrong to assume the OS would limit the memory my program could use? And also: is this a valid example of a memory leak? (I know other examples, when you don't free up memory before a function returns, but I'd like to know if this program I wrote is also a case of memory leak).

Comment: The OS will allow your program to use virtual memory which by default may be as much as 2 times the amount of RAM you have. If you are using a hard drive instead of a SSD, the swapping of pages to and from the hard drive can bring the whole system to a crawl.

Comment: ***is this a valid example of a memory leak?*** Yes of course. You have no way to delete the memory you allocate since you don't keep a pointer to each block allocated.

Comment: *was I wrong to assume the OS[?]* Yep. Tell the computer to do something dumb and it'll do something dumb. Sometimes dumber than you expected because the computer's been optimized to do something that's really really smart in the 99 percent of cases that make up most of the activity it's likely to see.

Comment: Your OS is not magic and it won't protect you from doing stupid things (sometimes it will, but not always).

Comment: @drescherjm virtual memory space on most contemporary Linux machines will be 2^64 - *much* more than just 2*physical memory...

Comment: Wouldn't the OOM killer terminate the application long before that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Any _decent_ OS will protect other users from one user doing something stupid. Having a whole system freeze because one user uses too much memory is a beginner's error. It's unclear how bad the situation was in this case - the mouse freezing may indicate a freeze of the desktop environment, which runs under the same user account. It might not be an entire system-wide freeze, but Ctrl-Alt-Delete should still work. The beginner's error in Windows is that its critical system management tool (Task Manager) doesn't run with the same protection as Ctrl-Alt-Delete.

Comment: @MSalters thanks for the clarification :) Actually, I didn't try ctrl+alt+delete but the shortcut ctrl+shift+esc and nothing happened. The task manager was already open, but the leaking program was on top and still the task manager window didn't get focus when I pressed those keys, so I assumed the whole system was either frozen or absolutely slow.

Comment: ***I assumed the whole system was either frozen or absolutely slow*** I would expect it's the latter unless you have a hardware or driver problem.

Comment: You may want to look into your page file settings.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's not a memory leak, because memory leak is when your program fails to release memory that no longer needed. Memory leaks can be even unnoticeable. Windows doesn't limit applications in using [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (capability for applications to employ more RAM memory than it is physically installed, and to isolate them from one another). Windows hangs, because it tries to serve all the apps (including yours that still claims new memory) currently running in the system, while managing the insufficient memory by backing up the RAM onto the hard drive. In cases where you need so much memory it's best to ask Windows for a notification on memory status by calling [CreateMemoryResourceNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-creatememoryresourcenotification?redirectedfrom=MSDN) . And I disagree with @drescherjm
on SSDs not being hanged in cases like that. Mine hangs!))

Comment: Definition of memory leak: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312069/the-best-memory-leak-definition