# MacOS `leaks` for Still Reachable Memory

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, malloc

Consider the following program, `memory-leak.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *p;
int main() {
  p = malloc(7);
  p = 0; // The memory is leaked here.
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile this with `clang memory-leak.c` and test the output with the built-in MacOS memory leak detector `leaks` using `leaks -quiet -atExit -- ./a.out`, I get (partly) the following output:

```
1 leak for 16 total leaked bytes.
```

However, if I remove the 'leaking' line like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *p;
int main() {
  p = malloc(7);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this file and again running `leaks` now (partly) returns:

```
0 leaks for 0 total leaked bytes.
```

The [man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/leaks/) for `leaks` shows that it is only [un-reachable memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312113/22673230) that is considered a leak. Is there a configuration to detect un-`free`'d reachable `malloc` segments?

Comment: Can you try compiling with `-g` to make sure that there is no optimization removing the call to `malloc`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri still 0 leaks after adding `-g`!